# size mismatch for linear.weight and linear.bias in Torch model

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the following code to load the model.

```
model.to(device)
checkpoint = torch.load("weights/vgg.pth")
if 'state_dict' in checkpoint:
    checkpoint = checkpoint['state_dict']
ckpt = {k.replace('module.', ''):v for k,v in checkpoint.items()}
model.load_state_dict(ckpt)
```

I am getting the error:

> ```
> self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for RepVGG:
>   size mismatch for linear.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000, 1280]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([8, 1280]).
>   size mismatch for linear.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([8]).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your current model is configured to provide classification into 8 classes (`num_class=8`). However, the checkpoint you are loading is of a VGG model pre-trained on ImageNet that has 1000 classes. Therefore, there is a mismatch in the dimensions of the weights and bias in the last layer.

Comment: actually, I'm trying to stream multiple RTSP cameras. while I run only two cameras it works well, when I try to run more than two RTSP, I got that error, Do any idea what have to do to solve this error?